# .astype("int") or .astype(int)? Any differences between with and without quote/double?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame and one of its column consist of float type objects. I want to convert to int. As I tried, both `.astype("int")` and `astype(int)` methods work. I just wonder whether there is/are any difference(s)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK there is no major difference...

`.astype(dtype)` should accept everything what is accepted by [numpy.dtype()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html).

Internally it does this:

```
dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
```